# Toronto - legal to fix car in home garage?

Tags: ontario, car

Is it legal for someone to fix up old cars in their home garage in Toronto (north York specifically)? Including painting the car, engine etc, essentially trying to bring a dead car back to life.

Comment: Is this a business or a hobby?

Comment: Title says "car" but text says "cars" - is it a one-time thing or a regular process? The latter sounds more like a business, although there's likely to be a grey area between hobbyist repairs (on a car you may subsequently sell) and a business buying and restoring old cars.

Answer (score 4):

It could be. You would have to check the [specific address here](https://map.toronto.ca/maps/map.jsp?app=ZBL_CONSULT), although not all properties are covered by By-Law 569-2013. This will give you the allowed uses. Picking a random residential-looking location, you might be stopped by §15.20.20.100 of the zoning bylaw, which restricts service shops to being located in non-residential buildings. There are also specific laws about [vehicle service shops](https://www.toronto.ca/zoning/bylaw_amendments/ZBL_NewProvision_Chapter150_94.htm), which may included a required 3 meter soft landscape perimeter and fence, depending on what is adjacent to the lot.

Answer (score 4):

### Check zoning law

What is and is not permitted on a given parcel of land will be spelled out there.

Most “industrial” uses are prohibited in residential zones but restoring a single car as a hobby may be allowed.

### Check environmental law

Spray painting is often regulated - usually it must be done in a proper booth. The disposal of hydrocarbons (fuel, oil, grease) is also controlled.

There will almost certainly be noise restrictions in these laws as well as zoning law.

### Check work health and safety law

These are often broader than people expect and can cover hobbyists, not just businesses.